# plotting multiple moving averages using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to plot multiple moving averages using a for loop but when i put in this code i get an error.

```
ma_day = [10,20,50]
for ma in ma_day:
column_name = "MA in %s days" %(str(ma))

AAPL[column_name]= AAPL['Adj Close'].rolling(window=ma).mean()
AAPL[['Adj Close', 'MA for 10 days', 'MA for 20 days', 'MA for 50 days']].plot(subplots=False, kind='line', 
                                                                       figsize=(10,4))
```

the error i get says `MA for 10 days`, `MA for 20 days`, `MA for 50days` not in index.
what should be the correct code please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would match the column names in your attempted plot to the *actual* column names.

In the line above, you are naming the columns with "**in**" and in your plotting you are using "**for**" in the name.

Yer pronouns gotta match!  :)